# How to find original values after using 'levels' function in R?

Tags: r, backtrace, levels

The situation is outlined below:

My input dataset is of the format

```
User    Phone
Tim     Iphone4
Jim     Iphone5
JIm     Samsung GS4
Tom     HTC One X
Jerry   Nokia
```

After using the following piece of code on the csv after it is read into the program:

```
UFONE <- as.data.frame(userphones)

user = levels(factor(UFONE[,1]))
phone = levels(factor(UFONE[,2]))
```

the results are unique ordered and numbered lists like shown below:

```
User --> Jerry(1), Jim(2), Tim(3), Tom(4)
Phone --> HTC One X(1), Iphone4(2), Iphone5(3), Nokia(4), Samsung GS4(5)
```

Using these numbers, I build a matrix as shown below and find eigenvector centrality of the users:

```
   1   2  3  4  5
1  0   0  0  1  0
2  0   0  1  0  1   
3  0   1  0  0  0 
4  1   0  0  0  0
```

My question is after finding centrality values, if i want to trace back a user, how do I do that from this numbered matrix.

Kindly let me know if you feel further information is required for this issue.

Comment: If you read it in using `read.csv`, it's already dataframe and you can regulate whether variables are factors using that function's `stringsAsFactors` argument, so you seem to be showing us unnecessary code.

Comment: Oh ...sorry about that. I will keep that in mind. Thank you for pointing it out.